# How to multiply with %<>% (from magrittr package) in R?

Tags: r, pipe, magrittr

Let's assign value to a variable:

```
thisIsANumberVariable <- 3
```

```
library(magrittr)
thisIsANumberVariable %<>% +5 #adds 5 to thisIsANumberVariable
thisIsANumberVariable
[1] 8
thisIsANumberVariable %<>% *6 # Should multiply thisIsANumberVariable by 8, but instead:
Error: unexpected '*' in "thisIsANumberVariable %<>% *"
```

Is there a way to multiply and assign simultaneously with %<>%?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option would be to use `` `*`() `` or the `multiply_by` alias (see e.g. `?magrittr::multiply_by` for a list of available aliases):

```r
thisIsANumberVariable <- 3

library(magrittr)

thisIsANumberVariable %<>% +5

thisIsANumberVariable
#> [1] 8

thisIsANumberVariable %<>% `*`(5)

thisIsANumberVariable
#> [1] 40

thisIsANumberVariable %<>% multiply_by(5)

thisIsANumberVariable
#> [1] 200
```

Answer (score 2):

The magrittr package provides a variety of aliases to use in place of symbols.  These include `add`, `multiply_by` and others.  See the Alias section in the vignette which is obtained via the R code `vignette("magrittr")` and to see them all try entering this:

```
help("extract", package = "magrittr")
```

For example, we can write

```
library(magrittr)

x <- 3
x %<>% multiply_by(5)
x
## [1] 15
```